# Multiple VPN's using openswan

Tags: vpn

I have a server that has 3 interfaces.  1 interface has ip 192.168.0.10 (eth0) and a second ip 192.168.0.11 (eth0:1) and the other 2 have ip's 192.168.6.10 (eth1) and 192.168.7.10(eth2).  I would like to use the server to create a VPN using Openswan to another server 192.168.1.10.  I have configured both sides and I can see the VPN works.

BUT in order to separate the .6 and the .7 traffic from each other, I have created 2 separate VPN's configured and connected to the 192.168.1.10 server and I can see they are both up.

The problem:
I can ping from the 192.168.6.0 and can get to the 192.168.1.10 but from the 192.168.7.0 subnet to the 192.168.1.10 server does not work.

I have all this configured in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 0
```

and the VPN's are both up on the 192.168.0.10 server.

but I can only see 192.168.1.10 from the 192.168.6.0/24 subnet.  What am I missing to see the 192.168.1.10 from the 192.168.7.0/24 network ?

Just note that both VPN's terminate on the same VPN server 192.168.1.10

Thanks